# ListView crashing down at start up

Tags: java, android, listview

In my progress of learning listview in android, I created a listview with items which when clicked, do a certain task. No syntax errors. But, the app crashes at start up. Please help.

```
package com.mavenmaverick.listviewtest;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

 public class ActivityExample extends ListActivity{

 static final String[] CHOICES = new String[]{

             "Open Website",
             "Open Contacts",
             "Open Phone Dialler"
      };

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {                    
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      setListAdapter((ListAdapter) new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, CHOICES));   
      getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
      getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);
      getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
      {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            switch (arg2) {
            case 0:
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://www.developer.android.com")));
                break;

            case 1:
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("content://contacts/people/")));
                break;

            case 2:
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("tel:22237589")));
                break;

            default:
                break;
            }

        }  

    });
 }
}
```

[image: LogCat]

Comment: Try this, goto `Project/Properties/Java Build Path/Order and Export` -- Make sure there's a check in front of Android Dependencies and the support library, if you use it.

Comment: I just checked. Things are okay there. What does the logcat say ?

Comment: Your Activity is apparently named `MainActivity` in your manifest, but it looks like you've named it `ActivityExample`. These need to match.

Comment: Also, please don't post pictures of your LogCat. Please post it as text, preferably in a pre-formatted code block.

Comment: @MikeM. : Working. Hats off to you! You are a pro!

Comment: Please post your Manifest.xml here..